# Where do new methods go?

Tags: perl, oop, design-patterns, anti-patterns

Let's say I have an object, Car, and it has sets of methods that are... disparate? Maybe getting Blob-like? (as in the antipattern, "blob") These methods operate in distinct enough sets and don't really criss-cross functionally.

```
Car
# methods related to suburban driving
  ->foo1
  ->foo2
# methods related city driving
  ->bar3
  ->bar4
```

Now let's say I wanted to add "off road driving" as one of the cases that my car object can support. If I add methods to the Car object, isn't that making it more blob like?

```
Car (augmented)
# methods related to suburban driving
  ->foo1
  ->foo2
# methods related city driving
  ->bar3
  ->bar4
# methods related off road driving
  ->blah5
  ->blah6
```

Should I:

A: **Subclass Car**. I can make an OffRoadCar extends Car object. But what if Car and OffRoadCar share the same data/state, and only differ by methods? OffRoadCar only "acts" more specifically than car, but isn't described any more specifically nor does it have unique fields. So instantiating an OffRoadCar is meaningless.

```
OffRoadCar extends Car
# methods related off road driving
  ->blah5
  ->blah6
```

B: **Consume Car with a Static Method**. Like OffRoadAdventure->Embark(Car). So the OffRoadAdventure class takes a Car object and has its way with it.

In C# this would be called an extension method.

I guess put another way is **what is the solution to the Blob antipattern**? Is it subclassing? Is it extension methods?

Also, another reason I wanted to silo out these methods is what if their implementation incurs some cost, like the inclusion of other classes/packages? I wouldn't want users of the core class to constantly pay for something they would never use. I figure making the cost explicit for the minority is worth the savings for the majority. And it makes the dependency graph more precise (and not blob-like).

PS - Implementation language is Perl.

Comment: Does Car have to be a class? Could Car actually be an ICar (interface)? I would suggest a route of composition over inheritance.

Comment: Car is already a real class that's in use. (it's actually an ORM artifact)

Answer (score 2):

With Perl you should be taking a good look at Moose and roles.

```
package Suburban;
use Moose::Role;

requires 'wheels';

sub 'foo1' {
  ...
}


sub 'foo2' {
  ...
}

package City;
use Moose::Role;

requires 'wheels';

sub 'bar3' {
  ...
}


sub 'bar4' {
  ...
}

package Offroad;
use Moose::Role;

requires 'wheels';

sub 'blah5' {
  ...
}


sub 'blah6' {
  ...
}

package UltraCar;
use Moose;

with qw/ Offroad City Suburban /;
has 'wheels' => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'Int', default => 4 );

package RentalCar;
use Moose;

with qw/ City Suburban /;
has 'wheels' => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'Int', default => 4 );

package Tricycle;
use Moose;

with qw/ Offroad /;
has 'wheels' => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'Int', default => 3 );
```

You can even add and remove roles at runtime.

Comment: How does this address the blob problem? A role/interface is for  disparate classes fulfilling the same contract.

Comment: The problem with the blob is that you are rolling all the functionality of the object into a single location. Using roles allows you to break out the disparate features into separate, testable code modules then apply them to your objects as needed. At runtime, yes, you still have the 'blobby god object', but at that point you're not really worried about that, because the issues with that antipattern are re: development. Since you can apply roles at runtime, you can also add roll only the functionality you need in and not take needless performance hits.

Comment: Your edits made that more clear. But per some technical limitations, we can't use Moose. I get what you're saying though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are in the right track. An elegant solution is to have `OffRoadCar` inherit from Car and override its `Drive()` method. That way, you can say:

```
Car myCar = new OffRoadCar();
myCar.Drive();
```

This will call the overridden `Drive()` method in the subclass, and you don't end up with a gazillion methods in a single "blob". Here's how the `Drive()` method in `OffRoadCar` may look like:

```
@Override
public void Drive()
{
/* code */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of subclassing the `Car` class, you could use some form of [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Here, the base ORM class and the decorators (say `OffRoadDecorator`) implement some common interface, and the behaviour of each decorator can be dynamically added to the original class.

The key difference here is that multiple decorators can be used on the same `Car` class, and it's up to your implementation to say how those should interact. There's nothing to stop you decorating your class using the `OffRoadDecorator` as well as the `SuburbanDecorator`, and you can decide exactly what that means for the car within the decorators.

(P.S. sorry I don't provide any code examples; my Perl is simply terrible. Have a look at [this page](http://perldesignpatterns.com/?DecoratorPattern) for some other examples.)

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer Mark and I'm not sure how deeply you want to go into this, but you could look into the idea of Method Resolution Order. Instead of the standard depth first search for methods, using [mro](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?mro) allows you to perform a breadth first search. See [this page](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?mro) on CPAN and [brian d foy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2766176/brian-d-foy)'s article [Use the C3 method resolution order in multiple inheritance](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/blog/1112) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Suburban, City and Offroad Driving sound like algorithms. Strategy Pattern might help here with Context being Car.